# http listener is not running on port 7001

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-apps

I am using oracle forms 11g with oracle database 11g. While running forms it's been showing an error that http listener is not running on port 7001. How can I resolve this? Error no is FRM-10142.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error you need to start the Weblogic Admin Server from the menu

[image]